# What is the difference between architecture of buildings in zero gravity and on Earth?

Tags: space, building-physics

how is the architecture of buildings in zero gravity (space) different from buildings on Earth. like there is no concept of floor and ceiling in zero gravity so how are the buildings or spaceships designed?

Comment: Buildings in space are more commonly known as "space vehicles (SV),"  or "spacecraft," or if they spend all of their time orbiting a planet, "satellites."

Comment: This question probably belongs on [the "Space Exploration" stackexchange](https://space.stackexchange.com/), it's not a physics question.

Comment: Please cite an example of a building in zero g that is known to exist today.

Comment: @TimWescott   https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/main/index.html

Comment: @puppetsockreinstateMonica: this sounds sarcastic but isn't meant to be: the ISS strikes me more as a bunch of vehicles bolted together than as a "building", and I'm not sure that I count near-earth orbit as "zero G" -- microgravity, yes, but if I'm getting my in-the-head math right the actual acceleration due to gravity is close to 1g, it's just that it's sort of counteracted by orbital mechanics -- but not totally, because of tidal effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A building on the surface of the earth must support its own weight against gravity. A building in space does not, but must instead withstand the acceleration and vibratory stresses from the rocket engines that boosted it into space.

A building on earth can be made of heavy materials like steel beams and concrete; a building in space must weigh as little as possible since it is so expensive to boost masses into orbit with rockets.

A building on earth does not have to be airtight, but one in space does (if it is to house humans), and the space building must be capable of being pressurized to between 10 and 15 PSI.

A building on earth has to withstand rain and snow, but one in space does not.

A building on earth has to withstand temperature changes over span of 120 degrees F; in space, it must withstand a range of 300 F or more.